# Angular the reactive form,it initialization is not verified

Tags: angular

Angular the reactive form,its initialization is not verified.
My code:

```
 this.user = new FormGroup({
      category: new FormControl(''),
      // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
      id: new FormControl(''),
      phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^1[0-9]{10}$/)]),
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
      idCard: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(/(^[1-9]\d{5}(18|19|([23]\d))\d{2}((0[1-9])|(10|11|12))(([0-2][1-9])|10|20|30|31)\d{3}[0-9Xx]$)|(^[1-9]\d{5}\d{2}((0[1-9])|(10|11|12))(([0-2][1-9])|10|20|30|31)\d{2}$)/)]),
      code: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
    });
  }
```

The effect now is：
            [image]

I mean, the checksum rule is not executed when the form is first rendered.
  Please help me, thank you.

Comment: can you describe your problem more clearly , more code 

Comment: did you put  this.user = new FormGroup({... in the constructor ?

Comment: hi,malbarmawi.i am sorrry...
I mean, the checksum rule is not executed when the form is first rendered.

Comment: @malbarmawi hi,i am sorry. My English is poor. I mean, the checksum rule is not executed when the form is first rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has 'touched' in AbstractControl.It can help us see if we have clicked on the control.
https://www.angular.cn/api/forms/AbstractControl#touched